# NewLine in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing

I was trying to set the text given below but for some reason `JEditorPane` is not recognizing
`\n` and printing everything in a single line.

```
this.jEditorPane2.setText("Hello how is the weather in \n California");
```

Is there any way to get a new line space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JEditorPane` should support HTML, try using `<br>` instead of `\n`.